# Quotes string literal r"()" doesn't work properly with setwd()

Tags: r, quotes, literals

I am trying to set a working directory in R on a networked drive. So the drive is not initialized. The pathway is similar (though I can't directly post an example) to this

```
\\NETWORK_DRIVE\DataFolder\YourFolder
```

using the Quote command `r"()"` I place the folder pathway into the function like so.

```
r"(\\NETWORK_DRIVE\DataFolder\YourFolder)"
```

and get the following output.

[image]

Great! This is exactly what I want. So I decide to just combine two functions:

```
setwd(r"(\\NETWORK_DRIVE\DataFolder\YourFolder)")
```

but is peculiar behavior that follows.

The **actual working directory** correctly becomes

```
//NETWORK_DRIVE/DataFolder/YourFolder
```

the issue is when you use the command `getwd()` from here. you then would get the following:

```
\\\\NETWORK_DRIVE/DataFolder/YourFolder
```

Which is harmless enough as it is. Unless you copy/paste this string into the `r"()"` command again, and *reset* your working directory, then use `getwd()` again. you would then get a much longer string like so.

[image]

I am not entirely convinced this is intended behavior of the string literal. This could create an infinite loop pretty quickly if you unintentionally code this type of command. Does anyone know why the `r"()"` command pastes fine into the string, gives the correct pathway, but then when using `getwd()` it pastes the network drive with forward slashes to begin with then single backslashes the rest of the way? I would expect the behavior to be logically be:

See literal forward slash, replace with double forward slash (to avoid escape characters)? Am I understanding something incorrectly?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Where you got `\\\\NETWORK_DRIVE\\DataFolder\\YourFolder` from? From a terminal dump? Then escaping is expected and does not show actual chars in memory.

Comment: well the >\\\\NETWORK_DRIVE\\DataFolder\\YourFolder is show in the picture where I got that, its from the r"()" console output within R Studio.

Comment: ?Quotes in R Console, its a base package from R Version >=4.0

Comment: "Raw character constants are also available using a syntax similar to the one used in C++: r"(...)" with ... any character sequence, except that it must not contain the closing sequence ‘⁠)"⁠’. The delimiter pairs [] and {} can also be used, and R can be used in place of r. For additional flexibility, a number of dashes can be placed between the opening quote and the opening delimiter, as long as the same number of dashes appear between the closing delimiter and the closing quote."
the idea being, if this behavior happens in R it might also be happening in C++

Comment: One comment that didn’t fit in my answer: you are confusing forward and backslashes! This is a forward slash: `/` (it *leans forward* in the direction of writing). And this is a backslash: `\ ` (it *leans backwards*).

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you’re seeing is entirely correct, and has nothing to do with raw string literals anyway — the exact same happens with any other strings.

To convince yourself of this, you can perform two experiments:

1. Use regular string literals to set the working directory, taking care to escape all backslashes:

   ```
   setwd("\\\\NETWORK_DRIVE\\DataFolder\\YourFolder")
   ```
2. Save the network path to a text file (using your text editor of choice) and use it to set the working directory:

   ```
   setwd(readLines("networkpath.txt"))
   ```

   … obviously inside the file `networkpath.txt` you do *not* escape the backslashes.

In all three cases (raw string literal, regular string literal, string read from a file) the `setwd` call succeeds, and subsequently calling `message(getwd())` shows the following output:

```
\\NETWORK_DRIVE/DataFolder/YourFolder
```

… so R converts path separators to forward slashes (which is mildly annoying but totally valid!) but otherwise preserves the path.

And of course when you call `getwd()` and display the result directly on the terminal, R (for better or for worse) shows you a vector representation of the deparsed *R string literal* instead of the *contents* of the string, so instead of the above, you get

```
[1] "\\\\NETWORK_DRIVE/DataFolder/YourFolder"
```

But this is unrelated to `setwd` and unrelated to raw string literals — it’s just what R does for *every* value that gets displayed on the interactive console.

---

With that out of the way, regarding your specific issue:

> Which is harmless enough as it is. Unless you copy/paste this string into the `r"()"` command again,

OK, first off, `r"(…)"` isn’t a *“command”*, just like `"…"` isn’t a command, or `# …` isn’t a command. Nothing gets executed. It’s a *syntax*. It’s merely a way of writing a string literal in code.

Secondly, why would copy and paste a regular string literal into your code and transform it into a raw string literal? It’s *already* escaped correctly. By adding `r"()"` around it, you are adding a further level of escaping (because that’s specifically what raw string literals do). Of course that changes the value of the string. — And, just to be clear, once again this has nothing to do with `setwd` or `getwd`. You get the *exact same* behaviour if you print the value of the raw string literal *itself*, and then copy and paste it.